# How to write trigger from given day and given time 

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Can anybody please tell me how to write a trigger in Quartz Scheduler which starts at Wednesday (17:23:12) and runs till Sunday (20:00:00). I am not sure about no. of repeations.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say how you should do this when you aren't sure about the number or timing of the repeats.   Knowing that would help decide which type of trigger to use (e.g. CronTrigger vs. SimpleTrigger).

However, regardless of the type of trigger, you would create a Date that is Wednesday at 17:23:12 and set that as the trigger's startTime property, and another Date that is Sunday at 20:00:00 and set that as the trigger's endTime property.

Then if a SimpleTrigger, you would set a repeat interval of XXX and a repeat count of "indefinitely".   If a CronTrigger you would set a cron expression that represents the time(s) of day that you want the firing to occur.